# Default selected Item in Connected web part

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I have a web part connected to another (provide a row to).
It shows the radio button that when clicked correctly provides the data to the second web part.

Can I have this radio button selected by default so that it automatically provides the filter data as soon as the page is loaded?

Thanks in advance

Sachin

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by XSTL web part connection. You can user sharepoint designer for it.

Pleaes ref the following link

http://sachinvkatkar.blogspot.com/